# Jquery adding active element function not working anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have this function which adds an `active` element to my header to show which page you are on, the website is built on wordpress and I have queried all my `.js` files properly and there are no errors in the console, I cant figure why it wont work.

Here is the function

```
$(".main-menu-list li, .mob-menu-list a").on("click", function (e) {
    let page = $(this).attr("href");
     if ($(this).hasClass("active-page")) {
        return false;
     }
     $(".page").fadeOut(400);
     $("." + page).fadeIn(400);
     $(".main-menu-list li, .mob-menu-list a").removeClass("active-page");
     $(this).addClass("active-page");
   return false;
 });
```

And here is the html code for the menu

```
<nav class="main-menu">
<ul id="menu-topmenu" class="main-menu-list">
    <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-54"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/" aria-current="page">Sākums</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/about-us/">Par mums</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/projects/">Projekti</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/news/">Jaunumi</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/partners/">Partneri</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/contacts/">Kontakti</a></li>
        </ul>   
</nav>
```

The css is just fine no problems there, this was working before but I cant see where i messed this up

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it seems to work (as below)

```js
$(".main-menu-list li, .mob-menu-list a").on("click", function (e) {
    let page = $(this).attr("href");
     if ($(this).hasClass("active-page")) {
        return false;
     }
     $(".page").fadeOut(400);
     $("." + page).fadeIn(400);
     $(".main-menu-list li, .mob-menu-list a").removeClass("active-page");
     $(this).addClass("active-page");
   return false;
 });
```

```css
.active-page {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-menu">
<ul id="menu-topmenu" class="main-menu-list">
    <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-54"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/" aria-current="page">Sākums</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/about-us/">Par mums</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/projects/">Projekti</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/news/">Jaunumi</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/partners/">Partneri</a></li>

        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://tilts.webserveris.lv/lv/contacts/">Kontakti</a></li>
        </ul>   
</nav>
```

WordPress occasional has JS conflicts so best to wrap in

```
(function($) {
    
// ADD JS HERE
    
})( jQuery );
```

Which basically tells WP to see the $ as jQuery, so your new code would be:

```
(function($) {
    
$(".main-menu-list li, .mob-menu-list a").on("click", function (e) {
    let page = $(this).attr("href");
     if ($(this).hasClass("active-page")) {
        return false;
     }
     $(".page").fadeOut(400);
     $("." + page).fadeIn(400);
     $(".main-menu-list li, .mob-menu-list a").removeClass("active-page");
     $(this).addClass("active-page");
   return false;
 });
    
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally find what was the problem I had to wrap my document in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

code here 

});
```